# Space in like in MySQL search AWS python

Tags: python, mysql, sql-like

Trying to query AWS database (newbie to this). Query is as below:

```
dfHealthData = pd.read_sql("SELECT YearStart, LocationDesc, Topic, Question, DataValue "
                               "FROM HealthData WHERE YearStart = '2018' AND DataValueType = 'Crude Prevalence' AND Question LIKE '%18 years'" , connection_string)
```

Want to get string which ends in ' 18 years' (or ideally '>=18 years', but the former will do).

Error is as below. 
Error retrieving from AWS: unsupported format character ' ' (0x20) at index 161

Comment: Looking at the character count it appears it does not like the space within '%18 years', unfortunately I am not too sure why, try '%18%years'?

Comment: Yes I thought that myself but I am absolutely sure it is. I think it must count the whitespace between the 2 lines or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` has a special meaning in python. Try to escape it:

```
dfHealthData = pd.read_sql("SELECT YearStart, LocationDesc, Topic, Question, DataValue FROM HealthData WHERE YearStart = '2018' AND DataValueType = 'Crude Prevalence' AND Question LIKE '%%18 years'" , connection_string)
```

Comment: Thanks! That is the answer.